# How to fix "re.error: unterminated character set at position" in Python?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-requests

I am currently programming a script to get lyrics from the website "[www.lyrics.com](https://www.lyrics.com)". I have this:

```
import os, string, re, requests

print("Enter lyrics.com site:")
url = input()

lyrics_raw_html = requests.get(url + '.html')
lyrics_raw = re.findall(r'<pre id=\"lyric-body-text\" class=\"lyric-body wselect-cnt\" dir=\"ltr\" data-lang=\"en\">([^]+)<\/pre>', lyrics_raw_html.text)
lyrics = re.sub(r'(<.+>)', '', lyrics_raw[0])

print(lyrics)
```

and when I input a page ([this](https://www.lyrics.com/lyric/5030218/Pink+Floyd/Daybreak.html) page for example) I get this error:

```
File "C:\Users\MYNAMEHERE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\sre_parse.py", line 532, in _parse
source.tell() - here)
re.error: unterminated character set at position 91
```

It seems to be from my regex, but after some tinkering, I have no idea what the problem is. Any help would be nice!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change `[^]+` to `[\s\S]+?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an ECMAScript compliant regex (the regex was probably written for that regex engine), `[^]` is used to match any char, it is a valid character class there that matches "anything but nothing", and thus matches everything.

You should use `[\s\S]*?` here instead of `[^]+` to match any 0+ chars, as few as possible.